# Подключение DLL к проекту С++

Tags: c++, dll

Если не сложно, обьясните смысл препроцессорной обработки:

```
#ifdef TRANS2QUIK_EXPORTS
#define TRANS2QUIK_API __declspec (dllexport)
#pragma message ("TRANS2QUIK_API defined as __declspec (dllexport)")
#else
#define TRANS2QUIK_API __declspec (dllimport)
#endif
```

полный код

```
#pragma once
#define TRANS2QUIK_API __declspec (dllimport)
extern "C" {

typedef void (__stdcall *TRANS2QUIK_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK) (long nConnectionEvent, long nExtendedErrorCode, LPCSTR lpcstrInfoMessage);
typedef void (__stdcall *TRANS2QUIK_TRANSACTION_REPLY_CALLBACK) (long nTransactionResult, long nTransactionExtendedErrorCode, long nTransactionReplyCode, DWORD dwTransId, double dOrderNum, LPCSTR lpcstrTransactionReplyMessage);

#define TRANS2QUIK_SUCCESS                      0
#define TRANS2QUIK_FAILED                       1
#define TRANS2QUIK_QUIK_TERMINAL_NOT_FOUND      2
#define TRANS2QUIK_DLL_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED    3
#define TRANS2QUIK_ALREADY_CONNECTED_TO_QUIK    4
#define TRANS2QUIK_WRONG_SYNTAX                 5
#define TRANS2QUIK_QUIK_NOT_CONNECTED           6
#define TRANS2QUIK_DLL_NOT_CONNECTED            7
#define TRANS2QUIK_QUIK_CONNECTED               8
#define TRANS2QUIK_QUIK_DISCONNECTED            9
#define TRANS2QUIK_DLL_CONNECTED                10
#define TRANS2QUIK_DLL_DISCONNECTED             11
#define TRANS2QUIK_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR      12
#define TRANS2QUIK_WRONG_CONNECTION_HANDLE      13
#define TRANS2QUIK_WRONG_INPUT_PARAMS           14

long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_SEND_SYNC_TRANSACTION (LPSTR lpstTransactionString, long* pnReplyCode, PDWORD pdwTransId, double* pdOrderNum, LPSTR lpstrResultMessage, DWORD dwResultMessageSize, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_SEND_ASYNC_TRANSACTION (LPSTR lpstTransactionString, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_CONNECT (LPSTR lpstConnectionParamsString, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_DISCONNECT (long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_SET_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK (TRANS2QUIK_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK pfConnectionStatusCallback, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_SET_TRANSACTIONS_REPLY_CALLBACK (TRANS2QUIK_TRANSACTION_REPLY_CALLBACK pfTransactionReplyCallback, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_IS_QUIK_CONNECTED (long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_IS_DLL_CONNECTED (long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
```

Comment: Хоть убей, не пойму в каком месте происходит связка с TRANS2QUIK.dll?

Comment: в свойствах проекта, не?
или `#pragma` должна быть соответствующая.

Comment: Вот такая: `#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")`

Comment: А если в свойствах, то где? (VS2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все просто.

TRANS2QUIK_API - это макрос, который ставится в определение функции. И говорит о принадлежности ф-ции к определенной библиотеке. В коде самой библиотеки определен макрос TRANS2QUIK_EXPORTS и поэтому ф-ции идут как экспортируемые, а в коде программы макрос TRANS2QUIK_EXPORTS не определен и за счет этого ф-ции идут как импортируемые, т.е. вызываемые из внешней DLL.

Дополнительная информация:

- [__declspec(dllimport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8fskxacy(v=VS.90).aspx)
- [__declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx)

Comment: А в чём смысл этого условия!?  
    #ifdef TRANS2QUIK_EXPORTS

Comment: Я объяснил - использование одного хидера для Ваших программ и самой библиотеки. `TRANS2QUIK_EXPORTS` определен только в коде самой библиотеки.

Comment: Хорошо, но почему нельзя указать просто:  
    #define TRANS2QUIK_API __declspec (dllimport)

Comment: Можно... А кто сказал, что нельзя? Просто разработчики хидер-файла взяли его из комплекта библиотеки и особо не запаривались написанием каких-либо других версий файла.

Comment: Ясно, а вот такая конструкция?
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

Comment: Если язык C++, то добавить к прототипу ф-ции `extern "C"`. Напоминаю, что `extern "C"` делает полезную вещь - заменяет cppшное манглирование имен. В бинаринике и в коде названия ф-ций выглядят по-разному. Например, ф-ция `square` (как в cpp) в бинарнике может выглядеть как @square$qi. В этом имени зашифрованы имя ф-ции и типы ее аргументов и возвращаемого значения. А с `extern "C"` эта же ф-ция в бинарнике будет выглядеть как _square

Comment: >Просто разработчики хидер-файла взяли его из комплекта библиотеки и особо не запаривались написанием каких-либо других версий файла

не совсем так. Более корректно звучало бы так: "просто для корректного использования одного и того же хидера как в библиотеке, так и в используемых ее программах"

Answer (score 0):

> Хоть убей, не пойму в каком месте происходит связка с TRANS2QUIK.dll?

или включить соответствующий TRANS2QUIK.LIB в проект (добавить этот файл в проект). Если этого файла у вас нет, то его можно получить утилитой implib, например из командной строки папки с либой так:
implib.exe TRANS2QUIK.LIB TRANS2QUIK.DLL