# Что такое __cplusplus?

Tags: c, c++

> Сделано вопросом из ответа в теме: [Подключение DLL к проекту С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18230/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-dll-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81) (@ХэшКод)

А что такое __cplusplus (по идее именованная константа), а где она изначально задаётся? И два знака подчёркивания для чего обычно используются? Один знак подчёркивания, как мне известно, ставится, чтобы показать сишную функцию?

**Дополнено.**

И ещё, почему разработчики не потрудились задифайнить:

1) `LPSTR`
2) `LPTSTR`
3) `DWORD`
4) `PDWORD`

полагаю,

1) `#define LPSTR char *`
2) `???`
3) `#define DWORD  unsigned long`
4) `#define PDWORD DWORD*`

Я прав? А что будет во 2 пункте?

Comment: О каких разработчиках идёт речь? О разработчиках компилятора?

Comment: Разработчики (по крайней мере MinGW) потрудились определить все это в windef.h и winnt.h через typedef.

Comment: `LPTSTR` - очевидно, что указатель на STRING из TCHAR'ов, т.е. TCHAR*. К тому же, лучше такие вещи делать не через макросы, а тайпдеф (`typedef`).

Comment: <i>И два знака подчёркивания для чего обычно используются</i><p>
Два знака подчеркивания в начале имени - это зарезервированные слова.
<i>Один знак подчёркивания, как мне известно, ставится, чтобы показать сишную функцию?</i><p>
Нет. Один знак подчеркивания добавится в название Сишной функции в бинарнике по отношению к тексту программы. Но называть свои ф-ции с подчеркивания не рекомендую - можно легко налететь потом на грабли.

Comment: "О каких разработчиках идёт речь? О разработчиках компилятора?"  
О разработчиках которые выложили dll+заголовочный файл, в котором есть эти типы данных!

Comment: А зачем им их объявлять? Подразумевается, что эти типы уже объявлены. Более того, если бы они объявили эти типы сами, то нарушили бы переносимость, которая и без того не ахти какая.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

__cplusplus это макрос, который задаётся компилятором. Макрос объявлен, если работает C++ компилятор, и не объявлен, если простой С.

Обычно это используется, чтобы вставлять конструкцию extern "C". Например, так

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void myfunction() {}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, для нынешнего стандарта __cplusplus определен как 199711L